# Create a mailbox in MS Exchange using Oracle PL/SQL or java (attach in oracle)?

Tags: java, oracle, exchange-server

How can I create a mailbox in MS Exchange using Oracle PL/SQL or java (attach in oracle)?
I've found API's to create letters, etc .. But I can't find how to create a mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

On Exchange server I created web-service (java). Web-service is run powershell-script for create mailbox.
I just get request to web-service in PL/SQL